Non-poisonous vine for chain-link fence
I'm looking for a vine species that fits the following:

Non-toxic (i.e. won't harm children if they touch or eat leaves/berries)
Can climb/grow on a chain link fence
Relatively drought tolerant, i.e. can survive in the Canadian Prairies
Can tolerate partial shade

Lots of the common suggestions for vines, like hops, Virginia creeper, trumpet honeysuckle, etc. all have poisonous leaves/berries, which isn't great when there's little children around that might eat the plants.

How would you feel about an annual you would need to reseed yearly?

@MackM I'm open to anything at this point!

There are a lot of edible plants you could try, if you don't mind the maintenance.
Grapes. If you find a variety you like that grows well there, though I'm not sure how fast they'll grow there. There are wild ones that might not have as good fruit, but maybe they'll grow better if they're native near you.
Nasturtium—you can train them to grow vertically, and they're completely edible. Might want to be careful though—my friends had them as kids and we always wanted to sample them!
Malabar Spinach. What I read said they can grow in Canada, but something else said more warm or tropical regions, so whatever zone you are!
Scarlett Runner Beans. They live/come back for around seven years.
If it helps, I lived all my childhood with a tiny backyard and lots of poisonous plants and berries all around. Our mom told us it would make us sick if we ate them, and I hated being sick so I never did. Might've helped with what a sickly child I was, though, haha.
Later, though, my friend taught me to suck on the honeysuckle (flowers) at the park and that was naughty.
